Disable spring ssl bundle configuration
I am using spring boot 3.2.
In my application.yml, I have the following property
spring:
    ssl:
       bundle:
          jks:
             server:
               keystore:
                 location: ssl.pfx

In my profile specific properties file application-local.yml, I want to disable this property so spring doesn't look for this file when it starts up. How do I do this? I added following and it doesn't help
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: false


How about moving it out of application.yml and putting it in application-prod.yml and any profiles that do require the key?

That would be my last option. As I have over 6 profiles and local profile is the only one where I want to disable this configuration.

I disabled the ssl configuration by adding this in my application-local.yml file
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslAutoConfiguration


it overrides all excludes
